# intranet prebuild solution for joomla

Tags: content-management-system, joomla, intranet

HI,

is there any prebuild solution for intranet deployment in joomla??. I know there are solutions for Frupal like drupal commons and atrium but is there anything for joomla??

Or if any one knows a step by step procedure for doing this with all good module?? I know how to setup and install joomla but configuring it and setting up is difficult and so i am looking for pre build solution

Comment: What kind of features do you need? Intranet deployment is a pretty broad description, that could be anything.

Comment: simple things BLog poll wiki news and forums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I will go with wordpress and mediawiki integration. Thanks for the help.